# vespa create user fails to create a new profile in db

Tags: jquery, database, profiling, vespa

get endpoint is working in vespa db installed in an ec2 server but while creating the new user in docname its giving us 500 error with logs in vespa as

1643432914.009710   172.18.3.75 24114/15    logserver   ADM.com.yahoo.logserver.handlers.logmetrics.LogMetricsHandler   event   count/1 name=log_message.error value=42
1643432914.009861   172.18.3.75 24114/15    logserver   ADM.com.yahoo.logserver.handlers.logmetrics.LogMetricsHandler   event   count/1 name=log_message.fatal value=0
1643432914.009925   172.18.3.75 24114/15    logserver   ADM.com.yahoo.logserver.handlers.logmetrics.LogMetricsHandler   event   count/1 name=log_message.info value=950
1643432914.009995   172.18.3.75 24114/15    logserver   ADM.com.yahoo.logserver.handlers.logmetrics.LogMetricsHandler   event   count/1 name=log_message.severe value=0
1643432914.010037   172.18.3.75 24114/15    logserver   ADM.com.yahoo.logserver.handlers.logmetrics.LogMetricsHandler   event   count/1 name=log_message.warning value=130
1643432924.702706   172.18.3.75 24118/38908 slobrok vespa-slobrok.slobrok.server.rpchooks   event   count/1 name="heartbeats_failed" value=0
1643432924.702762   172.18.3.75 24118/38908 slobrok vespa-slobrok.slobrok.server.rpchooks   event   count/1 name="register_reqs" value=0
1643432924.702771   172.18.3.75 24118/38908 slobrok vespa-slobrok.slobrok.server.rpchooks   event   count/1 name="mirror_reqs" value=97378
1643432924.702816   172.18.3.75 24118/38908 slobrok vespa-slobrok.slobrok.server.rpchooks   event   count/1 name="wantadd_reqs" value=0
1643432924.702827   172.18.3.75 24118/38908 slobrok vespa-slobrok.slobrok.server.rpchooks   event   count/1 name="doadd_reqs" value=0
1643432924.702834   172.18.3.75 24118/38908 slobrok vespa-slobrok.slobrok.server.rpchooks   event   count/1 name="doremove_reqs" value=0
1643432924.702841   172.18.3.75 24118/38908 slobrok vespa-slobrok.slobrok.server.rpchooks   event   count/1 name="admin_reqs" value=2
1643432924.702848   172.18.3.75 24118/38908 slobrok vespa-slobrok.slobrok.server.rpchooks   eve

Answer (score 0):

None of these messages indicate anything wrong (also, note that you can use vespa-logfmt to format and filter these log messages).

I don't know what "creating the new user in docname" means - there is no concept of a "user" in Vespa. To get any help you need to specify exactly what operation you are doing and exactly what the response is.

Comment: i






the db state is up we are able to run get query but while adding a profile we ere getting error

Comment: This is not to specify exactly what operation you are doing and exactly what the response is.